# Express middleware protected and unprotected routes

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have some routes under `/users` that I want to require an authentication token and some that I do not. In order to achieve this I have done the following.

```
var protected = express.Router();
var unprotected = express.Router();

unprotected.post('/', function(req, res, next) { // A
   // no auth required
   next();
});

protected.get('/', function(req, res, next) { // B
   // auth required
   next();
});

module.exports = {
    protected: protected,
    unprotected: unprotected
};
```

And then I mount those routes in the following way.

```
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/users', unprotected_middleware, users.unprotected); // C
app.use('/users', protected_middleware, users.protected); // D

app.use(resultHandler); // Middleware for sending the response (all routes) 
app.use(errorHandler);  // Middleware for handling errors (all routes)
```

When I make a POST to `/users` it runs the expected route, however when `next()` gets called the `protected_middleware` runs. This happens because it finds the next `/users` definition at the line marked with 'D'.

What is the recommended way to get around this?

For each resource I want the ability to have different middleware per route.

```
POST /users           (no auth)
GET /users            (requires auth)
DELETE /users/{id}    (requires auth and admin access)
```

Comment: If you have middleware for handling errors, have you tried `next( new Error('crap') )` etc.

Comment: Yes, the middleware works as expected for handling errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need two separate routers here, simply use the middlewares for protected and unprotected where needed (in the router get/post functions):

users.js:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', unprotected_middleware, 
   function(req, res, next) { // A
     // no auth required
     next();
  }
);

router.get('/', protected_middleware, 
    function(req, res, next) { // B
      // auth required
      next();
    }
);
module.exports = router;
```

and then:

```
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/users', users);

app.use(resultHandler); // Middleware for sending the response (all routes) 
app.use(errorHandler);
```

Comment: Cool, this was one of the potential solutions I was exploring. Seems like a nice reasonable solution.